# how to enable admission controller plugin on k8s where API server is deployed as a systemd service?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to apply podSecurityPolicy and try to test whether it's allowing me to create privileged pod.
Below is the podSecurityPolicy resource manifest.

```
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
metadata:
 name: podsecplcy
spec:
 hostIPC: false
 hostNetwork: false
 hostPID: false
 privileged: false
 readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
 hostPorts:
 - min: 10000
   max: 30000
 runAsUser:
  rule: RunAsAny
 fsGroup:
    rule: RunAsAny
 supplementalGroups:
    rule: RunAsAny
 seLinux:
    rule: RunAsAny
 volumes:
 - '*'
```

current psp as below

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get psp
NAME         PRIV    CAPS   SELINUX    RUNASUSER   FSGROUP    SUPGROUP   READONLYROOTFS   VOLUMES
podsecplcy   false          RunAsAny   RunAsAny    RunAsAny   RunAsAny   true             *
[root@master ~]#
```

After submitted the above manifest,i'm trying to create privileged pod using below manifest.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-privileged
spec:
  containers:
  - name: main
    image: alpine
    command: ["/bin/sleep", "999999"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

Without any issues the pod is created.I hope it should throw error since privileged pod creation is restricted through podSecurityPolicy.
Then i realized,it may be a admission controller plugin is not enabled and i saw which admission controller plugins are enabled by describe the kube-apiserver pod(Removed some lines for readability purpose) and able to see only NodeRestriction is enabled

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl -n kube-system describe po kube-apiserver-master.k8s
      --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
      --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
      --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true

**Attempt:**
Tried to edit /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/kubelet.service and changed ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet --enable-admission-plugins=Initializers,NamespaceLifecycle,NodeRestriction,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota
restarted kubelet service.But no luck

Now how to enable other admission controller plugins?
```

Comment: Hi, have You authorized user or service account to use Your psp? psp resource by itself does nothing.

Comment: @Piotr Malec for testing this i have created kubectl create ns psptest; kubectl create sa pspstestsa -n psptest;kubectl create clusterrole non-priv-role --verb=list,get,watch --resource=PodSecurityPolicy --resource-name=podsecplcy;kubectl create clusterrolebinding psprbtest --clusterrole=non-priv-role --serviceaccount=psptest:pspstestsa; added namespace and sa in pod create yaml and tried.Still privileged pod successfully created.So i hope we need to enable admission-plugin podSecurityPolicy to fix this issue.

Comment: How was Your cluster deployed? And what K8s version and infrastructure are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Locate the static pod manifest-path

From systemd status, you will be able to locate the kubelet unit file 
`systemctl status kubelet.service`

Do `cat /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service` (replace path with the one you got from above command)
Go to the directory which is pointing to `--pod-manifest-path=`

**2.** Open the yaml which starts kube-apiserver-master.k8s Pod

Example steps to locate YAML is below

```
cd /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
grep kube-apiserver-master.k8s *
```

**3.** Append `PodSecurityPolicy` to flag `--enable-admission-plugins=` in YAML file

**4.** Create a PSP and corresponding bindings for kube-system namespace

Create a PSP to grant access to pods in kube-system namespace including CNI

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodSecurityPolicy
metadata:
 annotations:
  seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/allowedProfileNames: '*'
 name: privileged
spec:
 allowedCapabilities:
 - '*'
 allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
 fsGroup:
  rule: 'RunAsAny'
 hostIPC: true
 hostNetwork: true
 hostPID: true
 hostPorts:
 - min: 0
   max: 65535
 privileged: true
 readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
 runAsUser:
  rule: 'RunAsAny'
 seLinux:
  rule: 'RunAsAny'
 supplementalGroups:
  rule: 'RunAsAny'
 volumes:
  - '*'
EOF
```

Cluster role which grants access to the privileged pod security policy

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
 name: privileged-psp
rules:
 - apiGroups:
   - policy
   resourceNames:
   - privileged
   resources:
   - podsecuritypolicies
   verbs:
   - use
EOF
```

Role binding

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
 name: kube-system-psp
 namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
 kind: ClusterRole
 name: privileged-psp
subjects:
 - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: Group
   name: system:nodes
 - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: Group
   name: system:serviceaccounts:kube-system
EOF
```

Comment: found the service file from systemd status - /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.But it was not having manifest path in that file.I found kube-apiserver.yaml in /etc/kubernetes/manifests.But after edit this file and append PodSecurityPolicy in --enable-admission-plugins=. i'm not able to see kube-apiserver-master.k8s pod in running in kubectl get po -n kube-system.After i restore the file with same previous status,the pod started and in running status.So it seems direct edit in yaml file is not allowed it seems

Comment: @user10953531, I've updated the answer with one more step that will create necessary roles and bindings along with a PSP so that api pod will start after enabling `PodSecurityPolicy`

Comment: excellent.now the edit of kube-apiserver.yaml file helped to enable psp.But now i have created  psp with privileged as false and create clusterrole and clusterrolebinding same as you created and removed namespace and group details from cluster rolebinding yaml file.Now i'm trying to create privilege pod and it is allowing me to create.But my expectation is it should not allow me to create privileged pod on any namespace since clusterrolebinding is not a namespaced resource(other then kube-system)

Comment: @user10953531, please create a new question with all details :)

Comment: Sure.i will create new question as podsecuritypolicy not working for non kube-system namespace resources